# What structure would be better for this assotiation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, relational-database

I want to store data relating product parts and their individual prices. The parts have different categories but they have keys in common such as :name, :manufacturer, :rating, :partnumber, etc.

As a beginner to programming I'm struggling to find the best set up for this: 
1) making a model for each part category; or 
2) making a general part model with those common keys and then making category models (that belong_to part model) with more in depth attributes.

How, then, should the price model relate to the other model(s), depending on choice 1 or 2?

Also, if there are alternative ways to the ones I thought of, please inform.

EDIT [1]: To be more specific, my system will gather prices and make a comparison. It will be a sort of pricegrabber but a lot more specific. So one Product will have many Prices.

Comment: try reading a little more about join tables and foreign keys. See [this tutorial](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/active-record-associations).

Comment: I'll definitely read more about that. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

There is no too much info exactly about your structure, but I can assume, that you need to get more info about [polymorphic association.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Comment: After I posted this question here I received the same suggestion from a friend who's a dev aswell. Seems like that's what I should do now, before stepping forward on this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, here is how I would structure the initial schema:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  belongs_to :category
end

class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

As far as `rating`, whether or not you would create a model depends on how rating is being populated.  If rating is decided by a single source, I would just store it as an attribute on the product model. If rating is determined by some calculation based on user inputs, you might consider having a `ratings table` that `belongs_to :product`.

Concerning price, it sounds like the best bet would be to store the price on the `Product model`. I would store price as a decimal with a precision of 8 and a scale of 2, which can be accomplished with the rails generator `rails g migration AddPriceToProducts price:decimal{8.2}` or directly in a migration like this:

```
class AddPriceToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :products, :price, :integer{8.2}
  end
end
```

This will store prices as a `BigDecimal`, allowing 6 digits to the left of the decimal and 2 digits to the right.

Lastly, if your app is intending to sell products, I recommend having a table called `InvoiceProducts` or something similar, that stores product price at the time of product being sold.  This will allow for accurate longterm data as product prices change or products are retired.

Comment: I just eddited the question to make it more detailed. To be more specific, my system will gather prices and make a comparison, helping people to find the best choice on online stores. A price change record is also wanted. It will be a sort of pricegrabber but a lot more specific. So as one Product will have many Prices I think it won't be a good choice to put a price attribute inside of a Product model, right?

Comment: Yes. Something like ```rails g model Prices product:references``` with ```has_many :prices``` in the Product model.